# Libgdx: how to save Preferences?

Tags: android, libgdx, preferences

Am I doing this wrong?
The preferences file is empty

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");
    prefs.putBoolean("debug",true);
    prefs.flush();
```

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. Please change the Name of your preferences and dont use whitespaces. For example take `options`.

Comment: @BennX Thanks it helped ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work properly the filename of the preferences should not contain whitespaces. So the fix in your case is:

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("MyPreferences");
    prefs.putBoolean("debug",true);
    prefs.flush();
```